# telegram stop and block bot telethon

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

Sorry for my English, I hope you can understand me.
The crux of the problem is this.
I am using **telethon** library and it suits me.
In Telegram, in the application, there is such a function as **"block the bot"** and **"delete the bot"**.
Deleting a bot is easy, there is a **client.delete_dialog** method and this method works. But I could not block. After deletion, the bot throws spam further on me. Maybe someone knows how to do this?

Comment: You'll have to use raw method BlockRequest https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/block.html

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Wow, I looked for this method in the documentation, but why I couldn't find it. Thank you. BlockRequest is the right solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, there is a raw method BlockRequest, so the issue was resolved. Thanks. The strange thing is that I reviewed all the methods but did not find it.
[enter link description here](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/block.html)